# Rails 3 form_for nested model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The form_for helper doesn't appear to work in Rails 3. I am trying to to build a form for model and its child model.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

In earlier versions of rails I would build the form like this:

```
-# Haml
- form_for @person do |f|
  ... (person fields here)
  - f.fields_for @person.address do |address_f|
    ... (address fields here)
```

How can I do this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 8):

With Rails3, you should use `= form_for` and `= fields_for` (and not `- form_for` and `- fields_for` as in Rails2).

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3 we need to use =form_for,=fields_for,=text_field_tag,etc..., In haml (-) symbol only evaluate the ruby code. If we need to display, we need to use (=) symbole.